# Connect google assistant with chromecast( like netflix)

Tags: chromecast, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

Is that possible to connect google assistant with chromecast like netflix.

suppose i have already developed an app for google assistant, app name is test and suppose i have something in the test app to show like report.

Is this possible that,I would say hey google, show report then. It should automatically search chromecast devices nearby and connect to near by chromecast device then show the report on that connected chromecast device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Since August 2018, voice commands officially work with the following apps:

> - Netflix
> - CW
> - CBS All Access
> - HBO Now
> - YouTube
> - YouTube TV
> - Viki
> - Crackle
> - Red Bull
> - Starz
> - Google Play Movies & TV (for videos you’ve already rented or purchased)

To use voice commands with Chromecast, you need a device with Google Assistant (such as the Google Home or Google Home Mini smart speaker), plus a phone or tablet with the Google Assistant app installed. Voice commands also work with some smart TVs that have Chromecast built in (see Google’s website for a list of supported sets). Check this [article](https://www.techhive.com/article/3297950/how-to-use-google-assistant-and-chromecast-to-control-your-tv.html) for more details.

Comment: I know All above options can play using voice command, even i am able to play songs etc using voice command in chromecast device. My question is that I have developed an google assistant app which has to show some reports on screen, when i run the app on device it works fine i.e shows the result in device screen.Now i want when i ask google home to run same app , the result should display in chromecast device.

Comment: I think that's out of scope based from the article. Sorry it didn't help your problem :(

Answer (score 0):

While casting from other sources works, an action is not able to provide content that can be casted to other devices.